# Need help designing android ripple buttons with drawable-v22

Tags: android

I'm currently designing an app using material design guidelines, and I'm wondering whether I can create a directory for ripple-drawables which will be used when the device is running a capable software version, and another directory to hold alternative buttons for incapable devices?

Basically I want my button below to be able to utilize lollipop's ripple effect on devices running lollipop, and otherwise use a different button for older devices. All help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: If  I may  you  should  change  text  to  something  like... Beyond your grades and  login  to  square  shape  some pastel colour and  text  to  give me a try but  not  login